# gtkmm почему не работает стиль нода для widget провайдера?

Tags: c++

`Gtk::StyleContext` имеет 2 метода для определения CSS провайдера: `add_provider()` и `add_provider_for_screen()`. Когда я задаю провайдер для скрина с `GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION` используя `Gtk::StyleContext` обьекта `Gtk::Window` и загружаю в него

```
this->_cssProvider->load_from_data("progress,trough {min-height: 50px;}");
```

Высота `Gtk::ProgressBar`'ов как и должно равна 50px, но вот мне нужно, чтобы разные окна имели свой собственный стиль. Потому я использую `add_provider()` задаю провайдер уже для собственно `Gtk::Widget` с `GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION`, а не `Gtk::Screen`. Оно работает, если задавать, например, цвет окнам используя `set_name()`, и стиль используя `#name {background-color: red}`. Но почему не работает

```
progress,trough {min-height: 50px;}
```

для `Gtk::ProgressBar`'ов, когда стиль задан не скрину а виджету?

Answer (score 0):

`add_provider()` работает только для одного обьекта которому задан, не включая детей, `add_provider_for_screen()` работает для всей программы, в моем случае каждое окно должно иметь свой провайдер стиля и я скорее всего должен розшарить провайдер по всем елементам окон